# Duplicate column names in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, view, mysql-error-1060

How do I avoid a dup column name error in MySQL when creating a VIEW on two tables that both have the same column name as shown here

```
CREATE VIEW db.VI_RegionCity AS SELECT
    Region.Name,
    City.Name
FROM
    db.Region Region,
    db.City City
WHERE
    Region.RegionCode = City.RegionCode



ERROR: Duplicate column name 'Name'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using alias for column name

```
CREATE VIEW db.VI_RegionCity AS SELECT
    Region.Name as Region_name,
    City.Name as City_name
...//rest of the query
```

Comment: Is there a way to use "select * ..." and JUST avoiding the duplicates? I have a table with 20 odd fields and only the IDs are in both tables. I don't want to type out all field names.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW db.VI_RegionCity AS SELECT
    Region.Name AS RegionName,
    City.Name AS CityName
FROM
    db.Region Region,
    db.City City
WHERE
    Region.RegionCode = City.RegionCode
```