# MySQL: How to COUNT the number of rows returned by a Complicated Query

Tags: php, mysql, count

This feels like it should be really easy, but I just can't get it and I've tried everything.

How can I *just* get the NUMBER OF ROWS returned by this query:

```
(SELECT Alias1 . *, 
        Alias2 . * 
 FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
 WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
        AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
        AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
               OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
        AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
        AND Alias2.Col7 LIKE 'blah6' 
 ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
 LIMIT  50) 

UNION 

(SELECT Alias1 . *, 
        Alias2 . * 
 FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
 WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
        AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
        AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
               OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
        AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
        AND Alias2.Col5 LIKE 'blah6' 
 ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
 LIMIT  50) 

UNION 

(SELECT Alias1 . *, 
        Alias2 . * 
 FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
 WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
        AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2'
        AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
               OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
        AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
 ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
 LIMIT  50)
```

I suppose I could just use PHP to execute the query and then do a `mysql_num_rows` on the results, but I want to do it directly with SQL because I heard that's faster as it saves a step.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The following is giving me error (#1060 - Duplicate column name 'Col1'):

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
            AND Alias2.Col7 LIKE 'blah6' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50) 

    UNION 

    (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
            AND Alias2.Col5 LIKE 'blah6' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50) 

    UNION 

    (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2'
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50)
   ) a
```

The following is giving me error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
            AND Alias2.Col7 LIKE 'blah6' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50) a

    UNION 

    (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2' 
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
            AND Alias2.Col5 LIKE 'blah6' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50) b

    UNION 

    (SELECT Alias1 . *, 
            Alias2 . * 
     FROM   Table1 AS Alias1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 USING ( Col1 ) 
     WHERE  Alias1.Col1 != 'blah1' 
            AND Alias1.Col2 LIKE 'blah2'
            AND ( Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah3' 
                   OR Alias1.Col3 LIKE 'blah4' ) 
            AND Alias1.Col4 = 'blah5' 
     ORDER  BY Alias1.Col6 DESC 
     LIMIT  50) c
   ) z
```

Comment: Why does wrapping the entire query in parentheses (making it a subquery) and doing a SELECT COUNT(*) on it fail to work? Does it return an error message?

Comment: What happens when you wrap it in Select Count(*) FROM( Your Long query)  AS CountThis.  Do you get a specific error, or do you get the wrong count?

Comment: You do not provide a good reason to not use `mysql_num_rows()`.  It is there for a reason... use it.  Why do you expect it to be slow?

Comment: I tried using `Select Count(*) from query` and it worked absolutely fine. Can you post what you exactly tried executing and the error that you got while using count?

Comment: @reggie:  What do you mean by the "inner sub query"?  Yes, I repeated the question and made it more specific because no one was able to answer it, and one particular answer was getting upvotes even though it did not work.

Comment: @Programmer: Does your query without the count keyword work?

Comment: @reggie:  Yes, my original query EXACTLY as I posted it in my post works perfectly.

Comment: @Programmer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2737/discussion-between-reggie-and-programmer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to COUNT the number of rows returned by a UNION Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149685/mysql-how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-a-union-query)

Comment: @Programmer - the crucial thing here was the *error message*.  By not including it in your original question you made a number of people waste their time looking at your code and trying to figure out the problem.  Once you posted the error it became obvious what the solution was.  Please remember this, and include all relevant details in any further questions you ask on SO.

Comment: It is not acceptable to repeat "the question and made it more specific because no one was able to answer it,". Please edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a unique alias for your Column `Col1` since it is used in a `join` which requires unique columns to match against each other. It will throw an error 1060 if it comes across duplicated columns. Check this: [Duplicate column names in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274769/duplicate-column-names-in-sql-query)

In your case, the MySQL gets confused with `Col1` in table 1 and table 2 and hence the error. Once you have used that, you can `SELECT COUNT(*) from YourQuery`

Comment: That worked! Also, just removing ', Alias2 . * ' from all 3 SELECTS worked as well. Thanks reggie!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your entire query in parentheses (make it a subquery) and do a select count(*) from it:

```
select count(*) from (YOUR HUGE QUERY UNION YOUR HUGE QUERY) a
```

Comment: The actual error is:  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: try putting an alias after each of your UNIONED queries. i.e. select count(*) from ((select ...) a union (select ...) b union (select ...) c) a

Comment: Another ERROR:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;   I will edit my post so you can see what I'm inputting.

Comment: Please see the EDIT in my post for the errors I'm getting from your suggestions.

Comment: You get the same error if you add "AS a" instead of "a" for the table aliases?

Comment: Yes.  Any other ideas?  This can't be THIS complicated, can it?  Or is it just easier to use PHP to count the rows when a query is this complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole query as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (<Your query>)
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

Really use `mysql_num_rows`. For the union the database needs to build a temporary table anyway, which is the costly thing. Even if it were possible to do straight within SQL you won't save much by asking MySQL to give you that number.

The data isn't sent to PHP when you just use the `mysql_num_rows` function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a unique alias for your Column `Col1` since it is used in a `join` which requires unique columns to match against each other. It will throw an error 1060 if it comes across duplicated columns. Check this: [Duplicate column names in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274769/duplicate-column-names-in-sql-query)

In your case, the MySQL gets confused with `Col1` in table 1 and table 2 and hence the error. Once you have used that, you can `SELECT COUNT(*) from YourQuery`

Comment: That worked!  Also, just removing ', Alias2 . * ' from all 3 SELECTS worked as well.  Thanks reggie!